# Importing Leaflet Draw NGX for angular 4

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-directive, ngx-leaflet

I followed the steps from the main git: 
https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet

first I installed the required libraries (leaflet, leaflet-draw, leaflet-ngx, and leaflet-draw-ngx)

then I declared the required directive imports in app.module.

In my view I set the following:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="height: 400px;"
         leaflet
         leafletDraw
         [leafletOptions]="options"
         [leafletLayers]="layers"
         [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl"
         [leafletDrawOptions]="drawOptions">
</div>
```

but I get the following error:

```
> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'leafletDrawOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("fletDraw [leafletOptions]="options" [leafletLayers]="layers" [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl" [ERROR ->][leafletDrawOptions]="drawOptions"> </div> <div class="col-md-6"> <table class="table table-striped c"): ng:///gxxxx.html@0:258
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js?524d:1689)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.es5.js?524d:12802)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.es5.js?524d:26852)
    at eval (compiler.es5.js?524d:26772)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.es5.js?524d:26772)
    at eval (compiler.es5.js?524d:26659)
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js?524d:1679)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js?524d:26658)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync
```

I am new to angular 4, I'm I doing something wrong ? or is it related to ES version ?

Comment: Do you have your component in a sub-module of your project? If so, you need to add LeafletModule and LeafletDrawModule to that sub-module as well. The error you're seeing usually means that modules aren't being loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import the Leaflet and LeafletDraw modules into the module in which your component is defined (not just in AppModule).

In your AppModule.ts:

```
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { LeafletDrawModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw.module';
...
imports: [
    ...
    LeafletModule.forRoot(),
    LeafletDrawModule.forRoot()
]
...
```

In the component's module:

```
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { LeafletDrawModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw.module';
...
imports: [
    ...
    LeafletModule,
    LeafletDrawModule
]
...
```